# Chrome is firing 'Ctrl+C' keydown and keyup events when selecting text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I am dealing with keyboard events, and find that Google chrome will fire keydown and keyup events when I drag the mouse on the page to select some text. The wrongly fired events have keycodes of 17 and then 67, which stand for Ctrl and C. It just like I am pressing Ctrl+C on the keyboard, but I don't.

I use the following code to capture any keydown event and log its keyCode:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){ console.log(e.keyCode); }, false);
```

You may try to recreate the scenario.
This problem made me confused since I cannot identify which will be a true keyboard event and which is not.

I use Google Chrome 26.0.1410.
Many thanks to you guys who want a try.

Comment: Some friend say they can not see the effect, others say they can. I tried to disable all the extensions and plugins, it continued to fire the events.